# Swift 3 - setting rootviewcontroller delegate to navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, rootviewcontroller

In my Swift 3/Obj-C application, I'm trying to set the delegate of my rootviewcontroller to its navigation controller but am getting the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'NavController.Type' to type
>   'RootViewControllerDelegate'

**NavController.swift**

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc class NavController: UINavigationController, RootViewControllerDelegate {

    static func instantiate() -> NavController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavController") as? NavController

        let rootVC = navVC?.viewControllers.first as! RootViewController
        rootVC.delegate = self // <<<< ERROR OCCURS HERE

        return navVC
    }

    func pressedNextButton()
    {
        NSLog("Next button works!")
    }
}
```

**RootViewController.swift**

```
@objc protocol RootViewControllerDelegate {
    func pressedNextButton()
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@objc class RootViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var delegate: RootViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.delegate?.pressedNextButton()
    }
}
```

**MainProgram.m**

```
@interface MYQAddDeviceViewController () 
     @property (nonatomic, strong) NavController * navVC;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navVC = [NavController instantiate];
}
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve that error?

Comment: Why did you put @objc before the class definition?Both are subclasses of UIViewController.

Comment: Those swift classes are used in the Obj-C portion of my app which requires the use of @objc.

Comment: You get that for free by subclassing off of uiviewcontroller. In other words you no longer need it.

Comment: So you're correct about the NavController class but not about RootViewController. RootViewController needs the @objc bc the app uses RootViewControllerDelegate protocol which requires the prefix.  But, this exchange is not relevant to the question.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Sure. It's not really my wheelhouse, but I was hoping I could help. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because the line

```
rootVC.delegate = self
```

is inside a `static func` and in that context, `self` refers to an instance of the `NavController` metaclass, i.e. `NavController.Type` instead of `NavController`.

You want:

```
if let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavController") as? NavController,
    let rootVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as? RootViewController {

    rootVC.delegate = navVC
}
```